# Date comparison in Oracle where case when giving error

Tags: sql, oracle, date

> [Error] **ORA-00905** (21577: 32): PL/SQL: **ORA-00905**: missing keyword at 
>   to_date(last_update_date) >=  to_date(concat('01-OCT-',p_year-1))

```
SELECT SUM(trans_value) total, bectrn_id, becat_id
  FROM brvo_bemrc_transactions
 WHERE year = p_year
   AND trn_type = p_trntype
   AND doc_type = p_doctype
   AND company = p_company
   AND bedfn_id = p_bedfn_id
   AND bectrn_id = v_bectrn_id
   AND becat_id = v_becat_id
   AND CASE
         WHEN (extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (1, 2, 3)) THEN
          to_date(last_update_date) >= to_date(concat('01-OCT-', p_year - 1)) AND
          to_date(last_update_date) <= to_date(concat('31-DEC-', p_year - 1))
         WHEN (extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (4, 5, 6)) THEN
          to_date(last_update_date) >= to_date(concat('01-JAN-', p_year - 1)) AND
          to_date(last_update_date) <= to_date(concat('31-MAR-', p_year - 1))
         WHEN (extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (7, 8, 9)) THEN
          to_date(last_update_date) >= to_date(concat('01-APR-', p_year - 1)) AND
          to_date(last_update_date) <= to_date(concat('30-JUN-', p_year - 1))
         WHEN (extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (10, 11, 12)) THEN
          to_date(last_update_date) >= to_date(concat('01-JUL-', p_year - 1)) AND
          to_date(last_update_date) <= to_date(concat('30-SEP-', p_year - 1))
       END
 GROUP BY bectrn_id, becat_id;
```

Comment: Your query might be easier if you use `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q')` and/or `TRUNC(last_update_date, 'Q')`. Also [ADD_MONTHS(..., -3)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions011.htm#SQLRF00603) may help you.

Comment: Thanks @Wernfried Domscheit ..modifying my query

Comment: `to_date(concat('01-OCT-', p_year - 1))` only makes sense with certain settings. You are relying on the DBMS to guess you are using an English month abbreviatation, that the first two digits represent the day, that the last four digits are the year, and that date parts can be separated by dashes. Don't let the DBMS guess. Don't rely on Settings that may or may not match. Tell the DBMS what format you are using: `to_date(concat('01-OCT-', p_year - 1), 'dd-MON-yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = English')`.

Comment: As to your `CASE WHEN` expression: `CASE WHEN` must result in a value. And as Oracle SQL doesn't have a boolean type unfortunately, `to_date(last_update_date) >= to_date(concat('01-OCT-', p_year - 1)) AND to_date(last_update_date) <= to_date(concat('31-DEC-', p_year - 1))` is not a value (true or false, as it would be in some other DBMS).

Comment: It seems weird, that you are using `TO_DATE` on a date (`last_update_date`) in `to_date(last_update_date)`. What is this supposed to do? Is `last_update_date` not a date but a string? If so: It's a bad idea to store dates as strings in a database. And whenever you want to convert a string to a date, specify the format that you want used for the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Your `case .. when.. then .. end` is not proper.

Let us take last when to see what is wrong.

```
WHEN ( -- condition for thus WHEN starts from here
      extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (10,11,12) 
     ) -- condition for thus WHEN ends here
THEN -- THEN must contain value which will be the result of case statement if when condition is true
-- but your query has expression here
-- you need to put any value here
   to_date(last_update_date) >= to_date(concat('01-JUL-',p_year-1))
   AND to_date(last_update_date) <= to_date(concat('30-SEP',p_year-1))
END
```

I think you are looking for following query:

```
SELECT   SUM(trans_value) total ,
       bectrn_id ,
       becat_id
FROM     brvo_bemrc_transactions
WHERE    year = p_year
AND      trn_type = p_trntype
AND      doc_type = p_doctype
AND      company = p_company
AND      bedfn_id = p_bedfn_id
AND      bectrn_id= v_bectrn_id
AND      becat_id = v_becat_id
AND      CASE
            WHEN extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (1,2,3) 
                 AND to_date(last_update_date) BETWEEN to_date(concat('01-OCT-',p_year-1)) AND to_date(concat('31-DEC-',p_year-1)) 
            THEN 1
            WHEN extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (4,5,6) ) 
                 AND to_date(last_update_date) BETWEEN to_date(concat('01-JAN-',p_year-1)) AND to_date(concat('31-MAR-',p_year-1)) 
            THEN 1 
            WHEN extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (7,8,9) 
                 AND to_date(last_update_date) BETWEEN to_date(concat('01-APR-',p_year-1)) AND to_date(concat('30-JUN-',p_year-1)) 
            THEN 1
            WHEN extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (10,11,12) 
                 AND to_date(last_update_date) BETWEEN to_date(concat('01-JUL-',p_year-1)) AND to_date(concat('30-SEP',p_year-1)) 
            THEN 1 
         END = 1
GROUP BY bectrn_id,
       becat_id;
```

And yes, as suggested in comment by @Wernfried Domscheit, you can make your query easy according to logic.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks @Tejash...Actually in my Then statement , i need to check last_update_date range

Comment: inside then i need to set different range for each case

Comment: Yes, it is doing the same. You need to use case when in where statement like this.

Comment: please correct me if wrong.. in your edit we are putthing AND to_date(last_update_date) BETWEEN to_date(concat('01-OCT-',p_year-1)) AND to_date(concat('31-DEC-',p_year-1)) in when clause.. however this should be the result, not the conditon. can we put in like that

Comment: Nope. It will produce the result as 1 if condition met and it again compares with 1 so it will be the otherway round.

Answer (score 1):

I think your condition can be written much simpler like this:

```
WHERE ...
   AND TRUNC(last_update_date, 'Q') = TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -3), 'Q')
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to format the dates properly
2. Results of the `case..when` statements within the where clause
   shouldn't be boolean expressions and they should be splitted by

   `to_date(last_update_date) >= case when ...` and

   `to_date(last_update_date) < case when ...` into two parts,
   respectively.

So, use :

```
SELECT SUM(trans_value) total, bectrn_id, becat_id
  FROM brvo_bemrc_transactions
 WHERE year = p_year
   AND trn_type = p_trntype
   AND doc_type = p_doctype
   AND company = p_company
   AND bedfn_id = p_bedfn_id
   AND bectrn_id = v_bectrn_id
   AND becat_id = v_becat_id
   AND to_date(last_update_date) >=
       CASE
         WHEN (extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (1, 2, 3)) THEN
           to_date(concat('01-OCT-', p_year - 1),'DD-MON-YYYY') 
         WHEN (extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (4, 5, 6)) THEN
           to_date(concat('01-JAN-', p_year - 1),'DD-MON-YYYY')
         WHEN (extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (7, 8, 9)) THEN
           to_date(concat('01-APR-', p_year - 1),'DD-MON-YYYY')
         WHEN (extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (10, 11, 12)) THEN
           to_date(concat('01-JUL-', p_year - 1),'DD-MON-YYYY')
       END
   AND to_date(last_update_date) <
       CASE
         WHEN (extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (1, 2, 3)) THEN
           to_date(concat('31-DEC-', p_year - 1),'DD-MON-YYYY') 
         WHEN (extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (4, 5, 6)) THEN
           to_date(concat('31-MAR-', p_year - 1),'DD-MON-YYYY')
         WHEN (extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (7, 8, 9)) THEN
           to_date(concat('30-JUN-', p_year - 1),'DD-MON-YYYY')
         WHEN (extract(month FROM SYSDATE) IN (10, 11, 12)) THEN
           to_date(concat('30-SEP', p_year - 1),'DD-MON-YYYY')
       END    
 GROUP BY bectrn_id, becat_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query fails, because your `CASE` expression results in a boolean value, but Oracle's SQL doesn't have a boolean type.

We use a `CASE` expression when we want to create a boolean expression. This is typically used in the `SELECT` clause. The `WHERE` clause *is* already a boolean expression where it suffices to use `AND`, `OR` and parentheses to express what we are after. In your case you can even use a modulo operation to get from the current quarter of the year to the quarter you are interested in.

```
SELECT SUM(trans_value) total, bectrn_id, becat_id
  FROM brvo_bemrc_transactions
 WHERE year = p_year
   AND trn_type = p_trntype
   AND doc_type = p_doctype
   AND company = p_company
   AND bedfn_id = p_bedfn_id
   AND bectrn_id = v_bectrn_id
   AND becat_id = v_becat_id
   AND extract(year from last_update_date) = p_year - 1
   AND mod(to_number(to_char(last_update_date, 'q')), 4) + 1 = to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'q'))
 GROUP BY bectrn_id, becat_id
 ORDER BY bectrn_id, becat_id;
```